# Beginner in Python: Directory help needed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

What I want to do here is that I want to create a list 'image_paths' which contains the path for all the .pgm files (except the 3.pgm file that I wish to use as a test image for the facial recognition program). For the images except '3.pgm' I want to superimpose them and for this I used one of the pictures from the database '8.pgm' as a base image, over which I applied the addWeighted() function which iterates through each of the paths in the image_paths list and keeps on adding each image over the base_image. I use the resize() in the for loop to keep the size of the images same.

I am using the AT&T facial database which has the format of .pgm files. What I am facing the issue is in the path line of code. Where I create a list of the paths of each .pgm file.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import os

path=['test/']

#Appends all paths of images in the list image_paths. **I am facing error in this line of code**
image_paths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if not f.endswith('2.pgm')]

#initializing a base_image over which other images will be superimposed
base_image=cv2.imread('8.jpg')

#resizing the base image so it matches the size of the database pics (113(rows),97(columns))
base_image=cv2.resize(base_image,(97,113))

#cv2.imshow('lol',base_image) //for testing purposes

for pics in image_paths:
    im=cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser(pics))
    base_image=cv2.addWeighted(base_image,0.5,im,0.5,0)
    base_image=cv2.resize(base_image(91,113))

cv2.imshow('compiledimg.jpg',imstack)

k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
if k == 27:         
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

elif k == ord('s'): 
    cv2.imwrite('compiledimg.jpg',imstack)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The error that I am facing is:

```
image_paths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if not f.endswith('2.pgm')]
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: It looks like `path` just needs to be the string`'test/'` and not a list.

Comment: But then how am I to iterate though each of the .pgm file in the 'test/' and add it to the base_image? 
I need a list which contains the absolute path of each .pgm file and then run a loop over the list and consecutively add each file on the base_image.

Comment: Without running the code myself, I imagine that the change I suggest will create `image_paths` just as you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you should change one line in your code: `path='test/'` and try it again.

Comment: Just tried. Not facing the same error but got a new one.
"The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op" at the line **base_image=cv2.addWeighted(base_image,0.5,im,0.5,0)** Which is weird because I have used the resize function to make sure the size remains same after each iteration.

Comment: I'm afraid that needs to be another question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Alright! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it was a simple syntax issue.

the line:

```
path=['test/']
```

is to be changed to:

```
path='test/'
```

thank you quamrana.

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining `path=['test/']`, the python interpreter thinks that you are defining a list. However, since you aren't, you need to get rid of the square brackets and make path a string. So the correct syntax would be `path='test/'`.